# WebUI.getText() returns empty String

Tags: katalon-studio

I want to get the text of my TestObject, I use WebUI.getText(). My code works fine for one of my pages but fails for another page. I can't figure out why it fails, everything is literally the same and it should not fail. This is what I am doing:

```
    @Keyword
public boolean verifyIPAddr(Socket socket){
    //create test object for the ip header
    TestObject ipHeader =  new TestObject().addProperty("id", ConditionType.EQUALS, 'ipaddr-in-header')
    WebUI.waitForElementPresent(ipHeader, 20, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)

    //get text (IP) from ipHeader
    String ipHeaderStr = WebUI.getText(ipHeader)
    KeywordUtil.logInfo("ipHeaderStr: " + ipHeaderStr.toString())
    //split the ipHeaderStr so that "IP: " portion can be removed and only "0.0.0.0" portion is left 
    String[] ipHeaderStrArr = ipHeaderStr.split(' ')
    //store the ip in a variable
    String guiIPAddress = ipHeaderStrArr[1]

    //get the socket side ip
    String cassetteIP = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()
    KeywordUtil.logInfo(" address:" + cassetteIP)

    //validate that both are the same
    if(cassetteIP.equals(guiIPAddress)){
        KeywordUtil.logger.logPassed(guiIPAddress + " IP from GUI matches: " + cassetteIP + " from socket")
        return true;
    }
    else{
        KeywordUtil.logger.logFailed(guiIPAddress + " IP from GUI does not match: " + cassetteIP + " IP from socket")
         return false
         }
}
```

[image: stack-traces[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qeh6.png)

I am 100% it has something to do with WebUI.getText() but it's confusing me because it works for one page but fails for the other.

The following is the HTML for the working page:
[image: HTML]

The following is the HTML for the page that is not working:

[image: HTML2]

**Update:**

I just noticed that the one that was failing, fails sometimes and sometimes it passes, I still want to know how I can guarantee the behavior to stay stable.

Comment: Is the behavior of "works for one page but fails for the other" stable? did you got the same error everytime executing the test script?

Comment: Can you share the HTML? Are you using this keyword twice in the same test case or in separate test cases?

Comment: @MateMrše I am using this keyword for separate testcases. Each machine has the same GUI application, so I run this testcase on 2 separate test cases, it works for one but fails for the other

Comment: @TonyBui the one that it fails for, fails sometimes and sometimes it passes, I still don't know why.

Comment: I think it is not a problem of getText function. Could you add some hard wait WebUI.delay(some_second) to ensure that the text is there? Another option is trying to debug the script, moving each step.

Comment: @TonyBui so by adding a delay, it no longer fails, but the reason I didn't think of it as a delay issue is because it was perfectly stable for the other page, which is exactly the same code and same application, just a different IP

Comment: Delay works. That means you need to wait for the text visible before getting it. Each page, each element in each page (even in the same page) has different loading time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can try:

1. You can add a delay before getting the text of the element:

```
WebUI.delay(30)
```

2. You can prolong the wait

```
WebUI.waitForElementPresent(ipHeader, 60, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)
```

The reason is, Katalon (Selenium) code often depends on elements outside of its sphere of influence, like load times, network traffic, computer hardware, competing race-conditions, etc.

So, even with same code, sometimes the wait times will differ and that's why it is better to use flexible waits (like `waitForElement*()` methods).